# Alpakka - Akka-Http failure while downloading file with latest S3 Connector

Tags: akka, akka-stream, akka-http, alpakka

we are using alpakka latest S3 connector for downloading stream but it fails with max-length error 
as `` exceeded content length limit (8388608 bytes)! You can configure this by setting `akka.http.[server|client].parsing.max-content-length` or calling `HttpEntity.withSizeLimit` before materializing the dataBytes stream. `` ,stream as Source (downloading file from S3) and flow which calls to AMQP server using 
java amqp-client library , when we stream file less that 8M it process but larger file did not process and throw error 
highlighted above.

- Akka-http does not keep file in memory it streams directly from
  source , do we need to first keep file in memory and then stream it?
- Is Downstream i.e AMQP which is java client libary(5.3.0) is givig
  this issue , we are using One connection and one channel for Rabbit
  MQ?

  ```
  val source = s3Client.download(bucketName, key)._1.
  via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), Constant.BYTE_SIZE, 
  true).map(_.utf8String))

  val flow = Flow[String].mapAsync(
  //Calling future of posting message to rabbit MQ

  Future {
  //Rabbit MQ config Properties
  rabbitMQChannel.basicPublish(exchangeName, routingKey, amqpProperties, 
  message.toString.getBytes)
  }

  )     
  val result = source.via(flow).runWith(Sink.ignore)
  ```

Comment: Some additional Info , prior to this error i see this warning in logs ```[WARN] [08/31/2018 08:38:42.104] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [default/Pool(shared->https://abc.s3.amazonaws.com:443)] [1 (WaitingForEndOfResponseEntity)] Ongoing request [GET /(filename in S3) Empty] was dropped because pool is shutting down``` and this dispatcher default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3 , Will above error makes some message loss in large file processing?